# ServiceStack Proxy returns 200 but doesn't hit server

Tags: servicestack, reverse-proxy

I have plugged in 2 instances of `ProxyFeature` because I have APIs that calculate the  bearer token differently. One instance works fine, but the other always returns a 200 and an empty response body. I'm using Postman to query my ServiceStack API for testing.

**Not Working**

```cs
Plugins.Add(new ProxyFeature(
    r => r.PathInfo.StartsWith("/identity"),
    r => $"{services.IdentityServer.HostUrl}{r.RawUrl.Replace("/identity", "")}")
{
    ProxyRequestFilter = async (req, downstreamRequest) =>
    {
        // Customize the HTTP Request Headers that are sent to downstream server
        var myToken = MyLogicForTheTokenToUse();

        downstreamRequest.AddBearerToken(myToken);

        logger.DebugFormat("serialize: {request}", JsonSerializer.Serialize(downstreamRequest));
        logger.DebugFormat("Authorization: {Authorization}", downstreamRequest.Headers["Authorization"]);
    }
});
```

The log statements show me a good request. It looks good enough for me to manually execute them. The authorization header is "Bearer MyTokenValue". The URL is the correct value too.

Am I misinterpreting the info? What am I missing?

I have inspected the body  in `TransformRequest`. I see the body from my original request. So that is good.

I have not seen my loggers hit in `TransformResponse` or `ProxyResponseFilter`. I'm not sure how to interrupt all of this.

**Interruptions?**

1. My request made it to the downstream server, but it failed on that server and somehow Proxy didn't didn't tell me (Unlikely)
2. My request didn't leave my server because I screwed up somewhere (strong theory)

I'm leaning towards No 2, because the destination server is not logging any incoming requests. I know it CAN long them because I exercise it directly and see its logs.

How else do I troubleshoot this Proxy feature?

For reference, here is my proxy feature that works

```cs
Plugins.Add(new ProxyFeature(
    r => r.PathInfo.StartsWith("/benefits"),
    r => $"{services.BenefitsApi.HostUrl}{r.RawUrl.Replace("/benefits", "")}")
{
    ProxyRequestFilter = async (req, downstreamRequest) =>
    {
        // Customize the HTTP Request Headers that are sent to downstream server
        logger.DebugFormat("event: {event}", "ProxyRequestFilter");

        var myToken = MyLogicForTheTokenToUse();
        var jsonApiClient = new JsonApiClient(services.BenefitsApi.HostUrl);
        var authenticationResponse = jsonApiClient.ApiAsync(new Authenticate()
        {
            provider = Constants.Authentication.BearerProviderName,
            oauth_token = myToken.Result
        });

        if (authenticationResponse.IsFaulted)
        {
            logger.ErrorFormat("Failed to authenticate with downstream service {downstreamUri}: {errorMessage}", services.BenefitsApi.HostUrl, authenticationResponse.Result.ErrorMessage);
        }

        downstreamRequest.AddBearerToken(authenticationResponse.Result.Response?.BearerToken);
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you not able to debug into the framework sources to see what's going on? Otherwise you should be able to take a local copy of [ProxyFeature.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/main/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/ProxyFeature.cs) and debug that.

Comment: Logging shows the request goes out, but none of the response methods hit. It also looks like the server I'm calling is not recording a request.